# Another network wifi connection in windows

Tags: wireless-networking

Currently, I'm using a pocket wifi for my internet connection.

I would like to buy a wifi router to use as my file and printer sharing connection.

Is it possible in windows to be connected with my pocket wifi and another wifi router at the same time?

I don't want to use my pocket wifi for my file and printer sharing, that's why I would like to buy a separate wifi router.

Also, is it possible to plug my pocket wifi to my wifi router and have it broadcast the wifi signal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No idea on plugging pockrt wifi into router, but yes, you can connect to both. However you need 2 wireless adapters. I'm assuming one is built into whatever pc you are using, but you'd have to buy yourself another one. Here's an example: [link](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/tp-link-mini-wireless-n-usb-adapter-black/2080328.p?skuId=2080328)

Comment: We're all using laptops to connect to our pocket wifi. So, you mean to say, each laptop should have additional wireless adapters to be able to connect to another wifi router should I buy one? Is there no way to do this in windows w/o buying another wifi adapter? I hope there's a built in function in windows where I can add another connection :/

Comment: If you intend for all of them to be connected to 2 things each at the same time, yes. Otherwise, you can just switch between networks whenever you need to. Also, I could be wrong on all of this, I'd suggest waiting for someone more expirienced to answer this first anyway )

Comment: The way I understand it, one adapter - one connection, that's the way I've always done it, and seen it done. But you can switch pretty easily between 2

Comment: Also, you should be able to write a batch script to automise the proccess if you're going to switch often